# Directional derivative of a scalar field in the direction of fastest increase of another such field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose $f,g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are scalar fields. What expression represents the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction in which $g$ is increasing the fastest?

Comment: What do you think? What is the direction of greatest increase in $g$, to start with?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, I think it's $\nabla g$, but I could be wrong...

Comment: No, you're right about that. Except by “direction” one probably means a unit vector, so you'd have to divide by the length of $\nabla g$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, so would it be $$\frac{\nabla f \cdot \nabla g}{|\nabla g|}$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector field encoding the greatest increase in $g$ is the gradient of $g$, so the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $\text{grad}(g)$ is just $\text{grad}(f)\bullet \text{grad}(g)$.

Comment: Shouldn't you normalize the gradient of $g$? (And on a TeXnical note: Use `\cdot` rather than `\bullet`, I think.)

Comment: I wouldn't, but if that's how it's defined then perhaps. You loose information when you normalize. For example say you want to take the directional derivative of a function $f$ with respect to some vector field $X$. Now imagine that you are a particle traveling along the flow of $X$, and at each point in your trajectory you are evaluating the function. Certainly the faster you are traveling (which depends on the length of the vectors in the field), the faster $f$ is changing, so when you normalize you are loosing all the information of the dynamics of the associated vector field.

Comment: Indeed you lose information. But that lies in the word “directional”: A non-zero vector can be seen as direction and magnitude, and “directional” sort of implies that you disregard the magnitude. For most purposes I much prefer not to normalize, but then the result should not be called a *directional* derivative. Part of the problem is the lack of good alternative terminology that avoids that tricky word.

Comment: Yes I agree. Then perhaps "directional derivatives" should be taken with respect to "direction fields", not vector fields.